# How can I use pg_dump to backup postgresql to remote host?

Tags: postgresql, backup, host

I need backup local server two postgresql databases to remote host, using `pg_dump` command and not use ssh. local server and remote host are all install postgresql.

how can I do it ?

such as:

database name: A,B

local server:1.2.3.4

remote server:5.6.7.8

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the remote host, use pg_dump's --host option to do the dump from the local server.

Comment: can I from local server backup to remote host?

Answer (score 1):

Just if somebody finds to this question via google:

as user postgres do on the localhost:

```
pg_dump -c <db_name> | psql -h <remotehost> <target_db_name>
```

e.g. for DB A on 1.2.3.4:

```
root@1.2.3.4: su postgres
postgres@1.2.3.4: pg_dump -c A | psql -h 5.6.7.8 A
```

The "-c" creates the drop/create statements, so take care ;)